Run locate.updatedb nightly, not weekly?
man locate.updatedb says that the database for locate is updated weekly.
That is confirmed by /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist, which has
<key>Weekday</key>
<integer>6</integer>

To run nightly instead of only on that weekday, as root I tried to remove that part:
plutil -remove StartCalendarInterval.Weekday /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
But that failed, "Operation not permitted," with no further explanation.
How can I cause updatedb to run nightly?
Sequoia 15.0.1, macbook pro, M3 pro.

The file that you tried to edit is on the read-only System volume and can't be modified, as you discovered. But you can make the change you want by following these steps.
1. Disable the built-in job to update the locate database
This step is optional, but it will prevent the database from being updated twice in one day, once a week.
sudo launchctl disable system/com.apple.locate

To revert this step:
sudo launchctl enable system/com.apple.locate

2. Create a new job to update the database
Copy the job file to the writable LaunchDaemon folder and give it a different name:
sudo cp -p /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/locate.plist

The name shown is just an example; you can use any (unique) name you want. Now edit the new file so that it reads as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>locate</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Background</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PathState</key>
        <dict>
            <key>/var/db/locate.database</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>3</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>15</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

Finally, start the new job:
sudo launchctl enable system/locate

To test the configuration, you can run the job immediately:
sudo launchctl kickstart system/locate


That last kickstart command fails for me, Could not find service "locate" in domain for system.  The same failure comes from launchctl print system/locate.  OTOH, launchctl print system, within "disabled services", shows com.apple.locate disabled, locate enabled.  Is that okay?

Try this: sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/locate.plist

Thanks!  After that, the kickstart worked.  A find command is busily whirring away in the background.

It's odd that the launchctl(1) man page describes that as a "legacy" command, implying that it's no longer needed, but apparently it is.
